# My shell script 'break' statement not working

Tags: bash, shell, loops, nested-loops, break

I want to break from my nested while loops.

Below is what i have tried in my code,

```
while [itretative condition]
do
   ...
   ...
      cat test1.json | while read line
      do
        ...
        ...
           cat test2.json | while read line
           do
             ...
             ...
                if [ "$taskstatus" = "RUNNING" ]
#when my task status reach running, i want to stop the script execution and end it.
                break 3       #break 3 or exit is not working for me.
                fi
           done
      done
done
```

Please suggest me how i can achieve this?

Comment: Your indentation is crazy, it's really hard to follow what's supposed to happen when the margin jumps randomly. Also, could you explain what you expect, and how the output is wrong?

Comment: Sorry about my indentation, my expectation is! when the task status reach "RUNNING" state.. i want the script to end gracefully, i do not want to loop further and test but end it.

Comment: If that's your whole script then `exit` will trivially do that. If you are unable to fix the question, I don't think you can get anyone to look at it. See also the guidance for creating a [mre].

Comment: Hi, i tried exit but it did not work out for me. Based on your suggestion i have made a representation of the code by removing all unnecessary information.

Comment: The pipes (`cat somefile | while ...`) run their contents in subshells, and a subshell can't break a loop in a parent shell (or exit a parent shell, or...). Can you replace the `cat` pipes with `while read ... done <somefile`?

Comment: Thank you, it worked :) . It was a subshell issue.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you use a pipe, you create a sub shell. Neiter `break` nor `exit` works over sub shell boundaries.

Even `trap` does not work over sub shell boundaries. But the option `set -E` tells Bash to inherit the error handler of the parent shell. By this you can reserve a special exit code to implement the `break` logic.

The following code is divided in an outer shell and a sub shell, which runs your code using pipes and creating further sub shells.

The error handler of the outer shell is not inherited by the sub shells, because trap handler inheritance is disabled by default. The error handler of the outer shell just checks for the reserved exit code (42 in the example) and treats this as no error.

In the first sub shell error handler inheritance is enabled by `set -E`. This means that all sub shells share the same error handler. The sub shell error handler just passes the error code through and terminates the shell. By this all sub shells are terminated.

```
#! /bin/bash

err()
{
  local err=$?
  if (( err == 42 )); then
    exit
  else
    exit $err
  fi
}
trap err ERR

(
  set -E

  err()
  {
    local err=$?
    exit $err
  }

  trap err ERR

  printf "%s\n" a b c | while read i; do
    echo $i
    printf "%s\n" x y z | while read j; do
      echo $j
      exit 42
    done
  done
)
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, `break` statement will not work across sub-shell created from a pipe. For the simple case that the pipe is simply `cat file | while`, it is possible to 'de-pipe' the expression with `while read ... done <somefile` (Gordon Davisson  comment above).

For the more general case, where the pipeline can contain arbitrary commands (`grep x file1`, and `grep y file2`, in the example below), possible to `de-pipe` the command (and allow the break to work over multiple levels) using one of the following: (1) here documents (2) process substitution.

With here documents: `<<<"$(commands)"`

```
while read x  ; do
   while read y ; do
       echo "$x/$y" ;
       [[ "$x" = d* ]] && echo BREAK && break 2 
   done <<< $(grep y file2); 
done <<< "$(grep x file1)"
```

With process substitution `< <(commands)`

```
while read x  ; do
    while read y ; do
        echo "$x/$y" ;
        [[ "$x" = d* ]] && echo FOO && break 2 ;
    done < <(grep y file2);
done < <(grep x file1)
```